# Is there Support .sql File in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I uploaded .sql file in sharepoint. Unfortunately; there is only a download option if I want to view it. Is there a way to maintain such files in Sharepoint other than in .txt file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I understand, .sql is struct Query Language Data file,so SharePoint not provide the default program to open .sql file.
If you are using MS SQL Server Database, you could download and install SQL Server Management Shell which supported to open .sql file:

[Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: thanks for you Answer. We have a .sql file which be updated often. That's why I was looking to upload it to SharePoint library.

Comment: Yes, SharePoint library can be the place which stored the .sql file, but if you want to open and update it, should use SSMS as suggested.

Comment: Presumes you can install SSMS, presumes SSMS understands your dialect. You should open in VSCode.  The short answer is get your stakeholders to buy something else, like Confluence. Sharepoint is just not the product for technology.